# parameter to anonymous function

Tags: scala, functional-programming

How do you send a parameter to an anonymous function in scala, i'm trying to translate this from scheme

```
(cdr (map (lambda (x) (* x x)) somelist )
```

i know cdr is just .tail

and that an anonymous function is like `(x: Int) => x * 2, 9`

any help appreciated.

Comment: you don't pass parameter when using `map`. map applies lambda to all elements of list.

Comment: i know the lamda receives the parameter x which in this case is every element of "some list"

Comment: already solved  List(1, 2, 3).map( (x: Int) => 2 * x)

Comment: As a random aside, you can pass the parameter to the anonymous closure like so:

((x : Int) => x * 2)(9)

or

((x : Int) => x * 2).apply(9)

I also forgot to add my favorite:

((x : Int) => x * 2)(v1 = 9)

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Also, `map` is missing an argument. What _is_ the language you are translating from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the question is, so this is to spark some more information (or other answers) than anything else:

```
List(1,2,3) map (x => x * x) tail // => List(4,9)
```

This is the same as:

```
//blasted Scala still gets me -- List(1,2,3).map(x => x * x).tail()
List(1,2,3).map(x => x * x).tail
```

Where `x => x * x` is the 'lambda' in both cases.

Above the type can be omitted because it can be inferred. However,

```
// need the type here because it can't be inferred from context
val square = (x: Int) => x * x
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to make two kinds of translation here:

1. From prefix notation (function precedes arguments) to infix/postfix notation (method between object and parameters).
2. From functional (function and data are not tightly bound) to object oriented (methods are bound to objects).

I'll use the dot notation in Scala, to make things more clear.

So, in Lisp you have `(function arguments)`, so it is pretty easy to identify what are the arguments to each function. In Scala you have `object.method(parameters)`, so let's go through each Lisp function to identify what are the arguments and what is the object.

On the other hand, some Lisp functions will do some operation to every argument it receives, which doesn't translate to how Scala methods work. In these cases, one would need to introduce additional methods to translate, most often a sequence's `map`.

**`CDR`**

As you mentioned, this is Scala's `tail`. Alas, `tail` is a parameterless method, and `cdr` only receives a single parameter as well, so there's no need to further translation. Therefore,

```
(cdr (map (lambda (x) (* x x)) somelist))
```

becomes a partially translated

```
(map (lambda (x) (* x x)) somelist ).tail
```

**`MAP`**

There's a missing argument in the example given, which is the result type. So let's assume there was a `'list` there. The translation here is more tricky, because `map`, in Scala, is a method on a collection, not on a function. So it is `somelist` which is the object, and `(lambda (x) (* x x))` the method's parameter.

The translation, then, is from the partially translated

```
(map (lambda (x) (* x x)) somelist).tail
```

to the still partially translated

```
somelist.map(lambda (x) (* x x)).tail
```

**`LAMBDA`**

This one is more tricky, as there is no method in Scala that is its equivalent, and there couldn't be, as no method would be able to bind variables. However, `lambda` is intrinsic to the language, with the following syntax:

```
(argument list) => expression
```

Therefore,

```
(lambda (x) (* x x))
```

translates (partially) into

```
((x) => (* x x))
```

Back to the example, we have

```
somelist.map(lambda (x) (* x x)).tail
```

becoming

```
somelist.map((x) => (* x x)).tail
```

There are two important points to make here, though. First, Lisp is dynamically typed, so there is no need to declare what is the type of `x`. That is not the case for Scala, which can make things difficult, as there is no common type for all numbers.

The second point, though, is that Scala has *type inference*, so it can infer the type of `x` from the type of `somelist`, which renders the above point moot *in this particular case*.

Finally,

**`*`**

Which can be often more tricky, because it *does*  apply to however many arguments you have. The usual translation of

```
(* arguments)
```

is

```
collection.reduceLeft((x, y) => x * y)
```

Where `collection` is some sort of collection containing all of the `arguments`.

In this case, however, there are exactly two arguments, so it can be translated to Scala's own `*`. So, for the final part of the translation, we take

```
somelist.map((x) => (* x x)).tail
```

and turn it into

```
somelist.map((x) => x * x).tail
```

I hope somewhere along the way there was the answer to your doubts.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you want, I don't know scheme, maybe this one:

```
val a = (x:Int) => x * 2
List(1,2,3).map(a)
List(1,2,3).map(_ * 2)
```

Comment: I just have to +1 for pulling out the _ :-)

Comment: or if you prefer your functional programming to be point free: `List(1,2,3) map (2 *)`